# Computing $\int_{-i\infty-\frac12}^{i\infty-\frac12}\frac{i^{-s}\Gamma ^2(-s)\Gamma (1+s)}{\Gamma (1-s)} \, ds$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm looking for a proof that
$$\displaystyle\int_{-i\infty-\frac12}^{i\infty-\frac12}\dfrac{i^{-s}\Gamma ^2(-s)\Gamma (1+s)}{\Gamma (1-s)} \, ds=2\pi i\ln (1+i).$$
The result comes from a calculator. When trying to evaluate this complex integral, I'm not able to compute
$$\displaystyle\int\frac{i^{-s}\Gamma ^2(-s)\Gamma (1+s)}{\Gamma (1-s)} \, ds$$
and then evaluate it at the limits.
Can the answer, $2\pi i\ln (1+i)$, be justified at all?

Comment: do you know complex analysis? look for poles, compute residues, shift contous etc etc

Comment: a calculator? how on earth did this go in a calculator?

Comment: I have begun playing with this. I will let you know if I give up, and I will post my work if I think I have succeeded.

Comment: After much noodling, there seems to be a residue of $\pi^2$ at $0$ if we use the half circle that is (mostly) in the left half plane to complete your integral and use the cauchy integral theorem, which causes me great concern about your result, though I could very well be making a mistake.

Comment: Then again, it may be easier to use the right half circle, since it avoids $0$ and gives residues only due to the $\Gamma(1+s)$. I will think more about this later, after my proper work is done.

Comment: Why don't you simplify first? $$\frac{\Gamma(-s)^2\Gamma(s+1)}{\Gamma(1-s)}=\frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s)} \, .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify first: $$\frac{\Gamma(-s)^2\Gamma(s+1)}{\Gamma(1-s)}=\frac{\pi}{s\sin(\pi s)}$$ and notice that you actually want to calculate the inverse Mellin transform evaluated at $x=i$. So you can also proceed inversely and calculate
$${\cal M\left(\ln(x+1)\right)} = \int_0^\infty \ln(1+x) \,x^{s-1} \, {\rm d}x = -\int_0^\infty \frac{x^s}{s(x+1)} \, {\rm d}x$$ with $-1<s<0$ and $-1/2 \in (-1,0)$. To evaluate the integral, you can introduce $$\frac{1}{x+1} = \int_0^\infty {\rm e}^{-(x+1)t} \, {\rm d}t$$ and substitute $u=xt$. The integrals then factorize and you can use the reflection formula for the Gamma function.

---

Concerning the other discussion about the vanishing of the integral over the arc $C$ of radius $R\notin {\mathbb N}$ for $R\rightarrow \infty$, observe the following:
$$\left| \int_C \frac{i^{-s} \, \pi}{s\sin(\pi s)} \, {\rm d}s \right| \stackrel{s=R {\rm e}^{it}}{=} \left| \int_0^\pi \frac{i \pi \, {\rm e}^{-i\pi R/2 \cos(t) + \pi R/2 \sin(t)}}{\sin\left(\pi R {\rm e}^{it}\right)} \, {\rm d}t \right| \\ \leq \int_0^\pi \frac{\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R/2 \sin(t)}}{|\sin\left(\pi R {\rm e}^{it}\right)|} \, {\rm d}t = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R/2 \sin(t)}}{\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\pi R\cos(t)\right) + \sinh^2\left(\pi R \sin(t)\right)}} \, {\rm d}t \\ \leq \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R t/2 }}{\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\pi R\cos(t)\right) + \sinh^2\left(2Rt\right)}} \, {\rm d}t $$
where in the second last step the symmetry about $t=\pi/2$ was exploited and in the last step use of $2t/\pi\leq\sin(t)\leq t$ was made. Choosing for $R$ the sequence $R_n=n+\frac{1}{2}$ and splitting the integral, the last line then continues as
$$= \left(\int_0^{\arccos\left(\frac{n+{1}/{4}}{n+{1}/{2}}\right)} + \int_{\arccos\left(\frac{n+{1}/{4}}{n+{1}/{2}}\right)}^{\pi/2} \right) \frac{2\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R_n t/2 } }{\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\pi R_n\cos(t)\right) + \sinh^2\left(2R_nt\right)}} \, {\rm d}t \\ \leq \underbrace{\int_0^{\arccos\left(\frac{n+1/4}{n+1/2}\right)} \frac{2\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R_n t/2 } \, {\rm d}t }{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \sinh^2\left(2R_nt\right)}}}_{\equiv I_1}  + \underbrace{\int_{\arccos\left(\frac{n+1/4}{n+1/2}\right)}^{\pi/2} \frac{2\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R_n t/2 } \, {\rm d}t }{\sinh\left(2R_nt\right)}}_{\equiv I_2}  \, .$$

The first integral vanishes manifestly as $n\rightarrow \infty$ since $$I_1 \leq \arccos\left(\frac{n+1/4}{n+1/2}\right) \cdot \max_{t\in \left[0,\arccos\left(\frac{n+1/4}{n+1/2}\right)\right]}\left(\frac{2\pi \, {\rm e}^{\pi R_n t/2 } }{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \sinh^2\left(2R_nt\right)}}\right)$$
while $\max(\cdot)$ is bounded, because $\pi/2 < 2$.

The second integral $I_2$ also vanishes upon inspection, because
$$R_n t \geq (n+1/2) \cdot \arccos\left(\frac{n+1/4}{n+1/2}\right) \geq \frac{n+1/2}{\sqrt{2n}} \left( 1 - \frac{11}{48n} \right) \sim \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$$ and again $\pi/2 < 2$.

Other arcs should work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Define $C$ be a circle centered on $x$-axis with radius $R$ that passes the point $(-{1\over 2},0)$. By tending $R$ to $\infty$, the circle contour tends to the same bounds of the integral. Note that $\Gamma(s)$ has simple singularities in non-positive integers. Therefore the function $$g(s)={\Gamma^2(-s)\over \Gamma(1-s)}$$has a singularity of order $2$ in $s=0$ and simple singularities in $s\in \Bbb N$.

By using $$s\Gamma(s)=\Gamma(s+1)$$we can write$$s(s+1)\cdots (s+n)\Gamma(s)=\Gamma(s+n+1)$$therefore$$\lim_{s\to -n}(s+n)\Gamma(s)={(-1)^n\over n!}$$

Therefore the residue of $g(s)$ at a positive integer singularity is$$\lim_{s\to n}(s-n){\Gamma^2(-s)\over \Gamma(1-s)}=\lim_{s\to n}{(s-n)^2\Gamma^2(-s)\over (s-n)\Gamma(1-s)}={(-1)^n (n-1)!\over (n!)^2}={(-1)^n\over n\times n!}$$and the residue of the integrand in $s=n$ becomes
$${(-1)^n i^{-n}\over n}={i^n\over n}$$
and the residue at $s=0$ is $$\lim_{s\to 0}{d\over ds}s^2\dfrac{i^{-s}\Gamma ^2(-s)\Gamma (1+s)}{\Gamma (1-s)}=\lim_{s\to 0}{d\over ds}i^{-s}\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(1+s)=\ln i$$therefore the summation of all residues becomes $$S=\ln i+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{i^n\over n}=\ln i+\ln (1-i)=\ln 1+i$$and the integral becomes $$I=2\pi i\times\text{sum of residues}=2\pi i\ln 1+i$$

Comment: I am absolutely not following this.  You lost me with your first line.  How does a circle centered on the x axis passing through the point (-1/2,0) tend to the same bounds as the integral?  And even if that is the case, then how do you know the integral over the large arc vanishes as $R \to \infty$?

Comment: The bounds of the integral show a line parallel to the $y$-axis passing through $(-0.5,0)$ which can be interpreted as a huge circle with radius $\infty$ passing through $(-0.5,0)$. Henceforth, I used the Cauchy theorem which states that **integrating a function analytic in $\Bbb C$ except some isolated singularities over a simple and closed path is equivalent to $2\pi i $ times the summation of the residues of the function in those singularities inscribed by that closed path.**

Comment: Also here is the link to the theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

Comment: As I draw out the limiting circles that should become the line, I only see, at best (and I am not even sure of this), circles passing through (-1/2,0) becoming **half the vertical line**.

Comment: Why half? Consider the family of the circles with $$\left(x-R+{1\over 2}\right)^2+y^2=R^2$$and tend $R$ to $\infty$. What region do the circles tend to?

Comment: Apologies, I misinterpreted you.  That is correct.  But you still leave out the question of convergence over the rest of the circle.  You are quoting Cauchy's theorem after all.

Comment: No mind at all. The convergence can be concluded by the summation of the residues i.e. the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{i^n\over n}$$ when $N\to\infty$

Comment: I disagree strongly with that.  Think about an integral over the arc.  Because the denominator of the integrand goes as $1/R$, the integral might not disappear as $R \to \infty$.  It depends on the exponential factor which, by my playing around, seems to me to disappear.  This implies a delta function in addition to the result at the very least.  I may be wrong, I have not worked things out completely, but I know enough to know that your computation is insufficient.

Comment: Back to the start, which part of the implications or the integral may result in divergence?

Comment: Just as I described it in the previous comment.  If you are using Cauchy's theorem, then I take it you know that the integral over *all* of the closed contour is zero?

Comment: No it is not. It is in fact equal to $2\pi i$ times the summation of the residues of the function in the singularities included by the contour. The integral is zero **only if** the function is analytic over the whole contour; on and inside.

Comment: @Mostafa: Gordon is right. You need to show the vanishing of the arc before you apply Cauchy's theorem. As you can see in my post the arc indeed vanishes for the specific choice $s=R{\rm e}^{it}$ and $t\in (0,\pi)$. The arc $s=-1/2+R {\rm e}^{it}$ with $t \in (\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ is slightly more complicated, but it should work the same.